# How to pass send_at argument to https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/singlesends?

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3

https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/single-sends/create-single-send says the https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/singlesends endpoint takes a `"send_at"` argument, but it gives me `"json could not be unmarshalled"`. Specifically:

```bash
curl -X POST "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/singlesends" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $SENDGRID_API_KEY" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"name": "Miss Christine Morgan"}'
```

works fine, but

```bash
curl -X POST "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/singlesends" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $SENDGRID_API_KEY" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"name": "Miss Christine Morgan", "send_at": "now"}'
```

and

```bash
curl -X POST "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/singlesends" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $SENDGRID_API_KEY" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"name": "Miss Christine Morgan", "send_at": "$(date --utc --iso=s --date='1 minute')"}'
```

return `{"errors":[{"field":"","message":"json could not be unmarshalled"}]}`.

Is the documentation just wrong, or am I passing the argument wrong?